# Generating a look up table for remote sensing data

Tags: excel, matlab, lookup-tables

I have two variable to which gives third as the output, I have these in Excel data and I want to create look up table in the MATLAB. Can you please the steps to be proceeded to generate LUT based on these two variables?

I tried using the in-built functions but I'm not getting how to proceed with Excel data set and now I want to try with coding.

Comment: Do you want MATLAB or Python? Please limit your question to get the most applicable answer. Are you stuck reading the Excel data? If you are then that should be your first question, before you even consider the LUT. If you already have the data being read in from Excel then the fact it started in Excel is immaterial to this question, please describe (with a [mcve]) which part of creating a LUT you are struggling with. Without these [edit]s to your question, it is currently too broad.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i need to do in matlab only. i have data in excel sheet, need to import and generate LUT.

Comment: As I say, which part are you stuck on, reading the data into MATLAB or creating a lookup table from the data? That's two questions, both of which have probably already been answered here or in the documentation (e.g. for `readtable` and `interp1`). Please [edit] your question to include a _specific_ [mcve] tailored to a single question

Comment: sorry again, im struck at importing the data having 3 column vectors (which are in excel in which two vectors are the inputs) into the 2 D look up table in.

Comment: You don't need to be sorry, but your question is unlikely to be answerable without [edit]ing it to include a [mcve]. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], and I suggest reading the documentation for the functions I mention above